# Smoothing out cloth

Tags: cloth-simulation

[image]
The vest isnt smooth around the shoulders when I did cloth simulation. Is there anyway I can smooth it out? When I go on sculpt mode the mesh deforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the modifier (or create a shape key with it). Then you can smooth it out.
Click the wrench icon on the right side, then the use the drop down menu of the modifier (Blender 2.9+)

[image: apply cloth modifier (2.9)]

Comment: Which modifier to I add?

Comment: @user107904 apply the 'Cloth modifier'. The cloth simulation adds it automatically when you activate 'Cloth' in the 'Physics Properties' tab

Comment: Oh ok. I already tried that, when I press 'apply' it becomes deformed

Comment: It says ‘Applied modifier not first So results may not be expected’

Comment: The mirror modifier is first

Comment: Ok, then you have to apply the mirror first, then the cloth modifier (modifiers work from top to bottom).

Comment: It worked! Thank you!

Comment: You need a complete shirt to get the cloth shape working. Apply the mirror modifier, run the simulation, then apply the cloth modifier. Done :-) If you want the mirror modifier back you can delete half of the mesh and add the modifier again & fix the center vertices if needed. IMHO clothes look better when they are not totally symmetric (wrinkles).